# Automapper flag enum

Tags: c#, enums, automapper

i am writing a mvc website that takes some information by viewmodels.
this is my db poco

```
public class ServiceTime : BaseEntity
{
    public int IdRestaurant { get; set; }
    public virtual Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
    public  Src.OrderStar.Entities.Day Day { get; set; }
    public string StartTime { get; set; }
    public string FinishTime { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my view model

```
public class ServiceTimeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int IdRestaurant { get; set; }
    public bool Monday { get; set; }
    public bool Tuesday { get; set; }
    public bool Wednesday { get; set; }
    public bool Thursday { get; set; }
    public bool Friday { get; set; }
    public bool Saturday { get; set; }
    public bool Sunday { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime FinishTime { get; set; }
}
```

i am converting these class to each other by automapper. i can easily convert ServiceTime to ServiceTimeModel by this configuration

```
cfg.CreateMap<ServiceTime, ServiceTimeModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Monday, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Day.HasFlag(Day.Monday)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Tuesday, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Day.HasFlag(Day.Tuesday)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Wednesday, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Day.HasFlag(Day.Wednesday)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Thursday, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Day.HasFlag(Day.Thursday)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Friday, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Day.HasFlag(Day.Friday)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Saturday, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Day.HasFlag(Day.Saturday)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Sunday, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Day.HasFlag(Day.Sunday)))
            .IgnoreAllNonExisting();
```

Bu i couldnt to the opposite of this, i mean couldn't solve how to bind ServiceTimeModel to ServiceTime

i want to bind five different days to flag enum

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably have to create a custom mapping function and use it like this:
`.ForMember(dest => dest.Day, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => GetDay(src)))`, in this method you would check which flag is set to `true` and assign proper day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *ResolveUsing* method and create your own implementation.
For example: (it's not nice, but works)

```
cfg.CreateMap<ProductServiceTimeModel, ProductServiceTime>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Day, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => 
    {
       Src.OrderStar.Entities.Day result = (src.Monday ? Day.Monday : 0) | (src.Tuesday ? Day.Tuesday: 0) | (src.Wednesday ? Day.Wednesday : 0) | (src.Thursday ? Day.Thursday: 0) | (src.Friday ? Day.Friday : 0) | (src.Saturday ? Day.Saturday : 0) | (src.Sunday ? Day.Sunday: 0);
       return result;
    }));
```